# Chasam Sofer on innovation

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, orthodox, chatam-sofer

There is a famous quote of the Chasam Sofer, in which he applies the principle stated in Mishna 'Orlah 3:9 (החדש אסור מן התורה בכל מקום) to the question of innovation within Judaism. Rather than stating that "new [grain] is forbidden by the Torah in every place", ie: both within the land of Israel and outside of it, he instead uses the same quote to suggest that "innovation is forbidden by the Torah in every instance".

Can anybody please provide me with the exact reference for this teshuva of his?

Comment: since there is nothing new under the sun, I don't worry about it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Hebrew Wikipedia has an [article](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%97%D7%93%D7%A9_%D7%90%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%A8_%D7%9E%D7%9F_%D7%94%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94) on this saying.  They provide the following references in footnote 2:

- [Shu"t Chasam Sofer OC 1:28](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14663&pgnum=26)
- [Shu"t Chasam Sofer OC 1:148](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14663&pgnum=114)
- [Shu"t Chasam Sofer OC 1:181](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14663&pgnum=140)
- [Shu"t Chasam Sofer YD 2:19](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1839&st=&pgnum=23&hilite=)

Comment: Thank you! I just edited it into your answer for you. I've so far checked the first and the last of those, but it's destroying my eyes to try to read such tiny print. I shall check the other two momentarily.

Comment: Also EH 3:69 3:130 4:29