# The Chatam Sofer & chadash asur me-haTorah hi

Tags: yashan-chadash, chatam-sofer

Can anyone point to when and where the Chatam Sofer uses "chadash asur me-haTorah hi" for the first time? Thanx!

EDIT: im aware of these sources in OC and EH but they all state "chadash assur min hatorah". im looking for the specific formulation of "chadash asur me-hatorah hi"

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya. See the post: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/28104/27180 it might be related to your question. See also the links mentioned in this thread.

Comment: Aside from the links brought by @mvs he also mentions in his Shu"t YD 19:4 - https://www.sefaria.org/Responsa_Chatam_Sofer%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.19.4?vhe=Pressburg,_1855-1864&lang=bi

Comment: im aware of these sources [and thx!] but they all state "chadash assur min hatorah". im looking for the specific formulation of "chadash asur me-hatorah hi".